# Impulse response functions in VAR & VEC models

Tags: vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model, impulse-response

Im using VAR & VEC IRFs to estimate price elasticity (estimate change in demand for a 1 unit 'shock' to price) and Id like to compare results from both VAR & VEC models, where appropriate. Im using daily data and the demand effect generally takes a number of weeks to stabilise to a steady state. It is more a case of having a portfolio of sites, and building a VEC model per site if appropriate (co-integration is valid) and then reverting to VAR if not.

Id be grateful for comments on my understanding/assumptions:

VAR IRFs return to 0 as the effect of the shock peters out, so I need to use the cumulative version in order to get the longer-run (permanent?) effect (e.g. after N periods)

VEC models can have trouble with cumulative IRFs (can become infinite?) and so Im thinking the Nth entry in the long run sequence (i.e. not cumulative) is a comparable quantity?

Is the difference between the 2 essentially down to the fact that VAR models are typically built on differenced data (stationary) whereas VEC models are not?

Thanks